# Progressbar on Waitform freezes using a Task run on another Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview, task

I have an application which gets data from Excel Sheets using OleDb.
On the Form I have controls so the user can filter the data to his needs.
For example, `FileSize`, `UserID`, `Rootpath` etc. This works perfectly.

After final selection the User has to press an "update" Button so I can filter the data based on his input. The result will be shown in a DataGridView.

However, since the Data on the Excel Sheets varies a lot, I used to have a ProgressBar on a second Form (`Waitform`) **or** make the DataGridView invisible while the ProgressBar on the UI is visible during the non-UI-Task (Data Collection).

I do know that I should use a Task or a Thread (or a BackGroundWorker) to keep the UI responsive.
That being said, it still freezes my whole application.

```
//Update Button which uses all the userdefined filters
private async void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WaitBarDatagrid.Visible = true; //Progressbar is called WaitBarDatagrid
    WaitBarDatagrid.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    WaitBarDatagrid.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;

    dataGridView1.Visible = false;
    await Task.Run(() => QueryToExcel());
    dataGridView1.DataSource = FileInfos;
    WaitBarDatagrid.Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
}

private void QueryToExcel()
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
    {
        string fSize;
        if (FileSizeComboBox.Text == "All Data")
        { fSize = "0"; }
        else if (FileSizeComboBox.Text == "> 1 MB")
        { fSize = "1000"; } // 1MB = 1000kB 
        else if (FileSizeComboBox.Text == "> 10 MB")
        { fSize = "10000"; } // 10MB = 10.000kB
        else if (FileSizeComboBox.Text == "> 100 MB")
        { fSize = "100000"; } // 100MB = 100.000kB 
        else if (FileSizeComboBox.Text == "> 1 GB")
        { fSize = "1000000"; } // 1 GB = 1000.000 kB
        else
            fSize = "0";

        // The following ensures that all possibilities of User Definition are covered
        string user = "";
        string size = "";
        string sep = ""; //Seperator

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserTextbox.Text))
        {
            user = $"[UserID] = '{UserTextbox.Text}'";
            sep = "AND";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileSizeComboBox.Text))
        {
            size = $"{sep} [File Size] >= {fSize}";
            sep = "AND";
        }                    

        //Final Where CLAUSE based on User Input
        //string command = $@"{user} {size}{sep} [Date] <= {DateBox.Value.ToOADate()}";
        string command = $@"{user} {size} {sep} [Date] <= {DateBox.Value.ToOADate()}";

        //Call Data from Excel
        string connectionString = GetConnectionString(Datapath + RootCombobox.Text);
        string query = $@"SELECT * from [FileInfos$]  WHERE ({command})";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                    FileInfos = dt;
                }
                catch (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }
            }                    
        }
    });
}
```

So far I also have tried to assign the values of the `Userinputs` to global variables and it will be changed in their correspondent events. However, even with invoke my UI freezes. Where does it come from?

Comment: *even with invoke my UI freezes*. It's invoking the UI thread that freezes it. Doing work on another thread is about not using the UI thread. If you invoke back... From what I can see here, you don't need to. You can pass to your  method (`QueryToExcel()`) all the required values (your Controls' properties) as strings and return a DataTable. You could change it in `private DataTable QueryToExcel(string[] paramarray)`  called as `var dt = await Task.Run(() => QueryToExcel(values[]));`. You didn't show anything related to a ProgressBar, but, since you're returning a DataTable...

Comment: Btw, since you're using a DataAdapter, you don't need this: `conn.Open();`. A MessageBox there is not a good idea. It's probably just for debugging, but you could just write the error in the Console (output window).

Comment: Hi @Jimi , I just figured it out for myself. I wish you have answered an hour before :) You are still a genius, please write it as answer so I can pick it as solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QueryToExcel()` method is supposed to queue the work to run on a  ThreadPool Thread, to let UI Thread continue its own work without freezing.
But you notice that the UI freezes anyway, saying:

> even with invoke my UI freezes

It's invoking the UI thread from another thread that freezes it.
Doing work on another thread is about not using the UI thread. If we invoke back the UI thread from a worker thread, the *effect* is lost (or partially lost, annoying in any case).

You're also using [Invoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke) instead of [BeginInvoke()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke). The latter is executed asynchronously: it returns immediately and can prevent deadlocks if the control invoked is busy or otherwise unreachable/unresponsive.
It won't prevent the UI from stuttering at times, anyway.

Looking at the code you presented here, it appears that there's no need to invoke the UI thread at all: the secondary thread just needs the properties values of some controls and then assigns a DataTable to a field.

It is then possible to pass to this method the required values as arguments, assigning the Controls' properties to some variables or to the properties of a class (so it's easier to understand what the arguments contain).

the worker method could be changed in

```
private DataTable QueryToExcel(string[] paramArray) 
Or
private DataTable QueryToExcel(SomeClass values)
```

and can be called as:

```
private async void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dt = await Task.Run(() => QueryToExcel(values));
    Or
    dataGridView1.DataSource = await Task.Run(() => QueryToExcel(values));
}
```

In `QueryToExcel()` to Excel:

- Access the `values` parameter to setup the query or other processing.
- Create the DB Connection and fill a DataTable/DataSet.
- **Dispose of all the disposable objects created (Connection/DataAdapter etc)**
- Return a DataTable

Comment: For now I assigned the Controls Properties into Variables and access them on to 'QueryToExcel()'. In that case it works fine. However using the 'using' in the DB Connection dispose the Connection/Adapter by itself, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does. That's the correct way to initialize an `OleDbConnection`. I posted that note not explicitly for you (many *forget* to do it). You could also declare the DataTable with a `using` statement. But that's another story :). Btw, if you donwnvoted Enigmativity's answer, please add a comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code basically jumps to a non-UI thread and then jumps back to the UI - it's almost as if you never left the UI thread.

What you need to do is do all of your UI work on the UI thread and only do non-UI work on the other thread.

Try this code:

```
// Define other methods and classes here
//Update Button which uses all the userdefined filters
private async void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WaitBarDatagrid.Visible = true; //Progressbar is called WaitBarDatagrid
                                    //    WaitBarDatagrid.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
                                    //    WaitBarDatagrid.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 30;

    dataGridView1.Visible = false;

    string fSize;
    if (FileSizeComboBox.Text == "All Data")
    { fSize = "0"; }
    else if (FileSizeComboBox.Text == "> 1 MB")
    { fSize = "1000"; } // 1MB = 1000kB 
    else if (FileSizeComboBox.Text == "> 10 MB")
    { fSize = "10000"; } // 10MB = 10.000kB
    else if (FileSizeComboBox.Text == "> 100 MB")
    { fSize = "100000"; } // 100MB = 100.000kB 
    else if (FileSizeComboBox.Text == "> 1 GB")
    { fSize = "1000000"; } // 1 GB = 1000.000 kB
    else
        fSize = "0";

    // The following ensures that all possibilities of User Definition are covered
    string user = "";
    string size = "";
    string sep = ""; //Seperator

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserTextbox.Text))
    {
        user = $"[UserID] = '{UserTextbox.Text}'";
        sep = "AND";
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileSizeComboBox.Text))
    {
        size = $"{sep} [File Size] >= {fSize}";
        sep = "AND";
    }

    //Final Where CLAUSE based on User Input
    //string command = $@"{user} {size}{sep} [Date] <= {DateBox.Value.ToOADate()}";
    string command = $@"{user} {size} {sep} [Date] <= {DateBox.Value.ToOADate()}";

    await Task.Run(() => QueryToExcel(command, RootCombobox.Text));
    dataGridView1.DataSource = FileInfos;
    WaitBarDatagrid.Visible = false;
    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
}

private void QueryToExcel(string command, string RootCombobox_Text)
{
    //Call Data from Excel
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString(Datapath + RootCombobox_Text);
    string query = $@"SELECT * from [FileInfos$]  WHERE ({command})";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
        {
            try
            {
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { FileInfos = dt; });
            }
            catch (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException ex)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's untested, but it should be close. Note that non of the UI elements are accessed or updated on any non-UI thread.